# Induced Electric field from uniform magnetic field problem

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I am trying to find the magnitude and direction of the induced electric field caused by a uniform magnetic field $ \vec B$, which is perpendicular to the plane of the page. The magnitude of the field is $B$ throughout a circular region of radius $R$ and $0$ everywhere else. The field has a positive field gradient $\frac{ dB}{dt} $.

First I want the magnetic field in the region $r < R$.
I know I am supposed to use Faraday's law which relates the induced EMF $\varepsilon$ to the rate of change of magnetic flux density: $$\varepsilon = - \frac{ d \Phi_B}{dt} $$
But do not understand how to find the magnetic flux for $r <R$ .
Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you know the definition of magnetic flux?

Comment: It's $\oint \vec B \cdot d \vec a$ but I don't see how to use it here as $0 \leq r < R$

Comment: What is special here? You know B,  you know the area.